# Chosing between "to work" or "working"

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

While looking for gerund and infinitive tests, I have found an interesting question whose answer isn't as simple as I think. In the question presented in bold below, we're asked to write the appropriate form of the verb ***work*** in the blank: **work**, **to work**, **working**.

> **My sister decided to take a job in the summer _____ in the local cinema to earn some extra money**.

I can't see any reason why "to work" cannot go in that place, however, it has the gerund form of the verb as the answer.

Would you mind helping that why  the infinitive doesn't seem OK there?

Comment: I'd avoid a sentence with three infinitives in a row: To take, to work, to earn. I'd prefer breaking it up with *working*.

Comment: "to"+infinitive expresses a goal or purpose in this context, e.g. "He bought a car to travel the world", "He took a job to earn money".

Comment: Ok. But what about these?                                      
 "He took a job to work at Tesla's battery factory." , "He landed a job to work for ESPN."                                                                                   
 "I got a job to work at Devils Tower National Monument."

Comment: Would "working" make a difference if used in place of "to work"?

Answer (score 1):

**Take a job *to work* in the local cinema**
This implies that the the reason you took the job was to work.  Most people don't take jobs for the simple pleasure of working. Specific to your example, her purpose is to earn money. This construction is seldom used

**Take a job *working* in the local cinema**
In this case, "working in the local cinema" describes the job she took.

[NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got%20a%20job%20to%20work%2Cgot%20a%20job%20working%2Ctook%20a%20job%20to%20work%2Ctook%20a%20job%20working&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20job%20to%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20job%20working%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctook%20a%20job%20working%3B%2Cc0) shows that the second usage is *far* more common than the first.

Comment: Lillia, a spy, took a job sweeping floors **to work** in the CIA's Mumsword Building. Helga, a maintenance engineer, took a job sweeping floors, **working** in the CIA's Mumsword Building.   Lillia took the job so she *could* work at the CIA (and now does).  Helga took the job and works at the CIA.

Answer (score 0):

> My sister decided to take a job in the summer _____ in the local cinema to earn some extra money.

As commented, with 'to work', we will have three infinitives.  I find it quite clumsy.

Also, there is a slight difference between the infinitive form and the participle form.  In this case, the former stresses on the 'work'; 'to work' is an *aim*.  The latter stresses on the *effect* of working.

If *working in the cinema* serves just to meet the aim, *to earn some extra money*, then we say

> My sister decided to take a job in the summer, *working* in the local cinema to earn some extra money.